# Simply Riddleculous

Tags: riddle, rhyme, number-sequence, steganography

<sup>An entry in the [19<sup>th</sup> fortnightly challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion) to which [I have been assigned](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33127729#33127729) [riddle](/questions/tagged/riddle) + [number-sequence](/questions/tagged/number-sequence) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja) who came up with the Uncoventional Tag Fusion Idea. If you have any queries you can ask them in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46051/unconventional-tag-fusion).</sup>

---

> Alright now, you should listen close.
>   A number sequence, lets see how it goes.
>   But of course, I'm not going to tell you.
>   Care to wait and I'll sell you a clue.
>   Even when you have no idea what to say.
>   Have faith and realise this is just a display
>   Maybe sometimes you should check before
>   Unfortunately I can't go on any more...

**What is the sequence?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The

> initial letters of the lines have indices 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 in the alphabet

so this is

> the Fibonacci sequence.

Most of the text is

> just scaffolding to provide a place for those initial letters to live.

As Deusovi's answer points out, the reason why "I can't go on any more" is that

> there is no 34th letter in our alphabet.

Beastly Gerbil also requests, in comments, an explanation for "Maybe sometimes you should just check before"; although this turns out not to be B.G.'s original intention, it works nicely as a reference to

> the fact that each Fibonacci number is derived from its two predecessors.

Comment: Damn! How quick can you get!!!!

Comment: Pretty much exactly that quick :-).

Comment: ^ :D Hahahaha May be quicker than a bullet

Comment: I see Deusovi was like 30 seconds behind.

Comment: Gah, you *just* beat me. My answer is *slightly* more detailed, though, so I'll use that as an excuse. :P

Comment: Too quick.... Damn it... I thought I had at last got one... :(

Comment: @Sid You can add an answer with a paragraph of explanation. That should get you some points :D

Comment: Oh, I see. (I don't think they're "before" -- they're *part* of each sentence. But never mind.)

Comment: (I see Deusovi made the same guess about it as I did.)

Comment: Yeah I actually prefer you're explanation so keep it

Comment: Ah, OK, will adjust again.

Answer (score 6):

The number sequence is

> the Fibonacci Sequence. The first letters of each lines are the sequence converted to letters (A=1...Z=26).

Alright now, you should listen close.

> Filler line.

A number sequence, lets see how it goes.

> Reminding us that we're looking for a number sequence.

But of course, I'm not going to tell you.

> Well, it's not stated in the riddle!

Care to wait and I'll sell you a clue.

> The more lines you read, the more clues you get.

Even when you have no idea what to say.

> Filler line.

Have faith and realise this is just a display

> The riddle itself "displays" the sequence with its first letters.

Maybe sometimes you should check before

> Each term refers to the previous terms. (And if you don't look at the previous lines, you don't have much of a chance of solving it!)

Unfortunately I can't go on any more...

> There's no 34th letter of the alphabet.

Comment: That was quick but not as quick as Gareth!

Comment: The look before bit was actually meant to be 'look before the sentence starts' so the first letter but your explanation is probably better!